# New RoleCenter page in EP ax 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, enterprise-portal

im trying to set security roles, privileges vs for my new rolecenter page. i've followed a way as mentioned below.

- created a page as a rolecenter page in EP deployed in ax 2012.
- assigned users for new rolecenter profile.
- created a role and duties-privileges-entry points for this user profile with security development tool.

while testing in ax 2012 rolecenter works correctly but when i try to sign in to EP im facing with an error. "Error: Access Denied ". other page links works correctly with same user.

any idea about what im missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following this guide, it's worked for me in the past (on AX 2009) but I think you missed some steps

http://msdax.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/how-to-create-a-new-role-centre-in-dynamics-ax-2009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup different security per Web Module, so you can check if that users has right for all modules.